# Qt out of memory allocating 136085 bytes

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, virtual-machine, out-of-memory

I don't understand this problem. I have a really small project and it worked before. I only changed a few files and got this error.

My .pro file is:

```
TARGET = Algorithms
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

INCLUDEPATH += include \    # Include path to my include files                              
               C:\includes    # Here is the complete Eigen library and Boost

SOURCES += \  Adding my src files
HEADERS += \  Adding my header files
```

My source and header files are together 1.5 MB, so it is really less. But if I compile I get the error above.

I run a virtual Windows 7 32 bit 8 GB RAM on the virtual machine.
And use the standard MinGW 32 bit kit for Qt 5.1.

What happens there?

Comment: Please, add the exact message and possibly the source code

Comment: 136085 bytes is around 0.130 MB

Comment: From *where* does the error come? Try to narrow it down, and then post the relevant code.

Comment: exact message is "out of memory allocating 136085 bytes" "cant find cc1plus.exe " but i didnt change anything? This should be included in QT or ? This error is not in my code i can compile the code without problems on other systems it is something with QT and with that i am really new

Comment: but when this file is missing it should not be possible for me to build some tutorials or other project... but i can do this ...there i get no error

Comment: btw, 8GB Ram on a 32bits system is useless

Comment: ok i reinstalld QT. Now i get only "out of memory allocating 136085 bytes" with "cc1plus.exe" but he didnt tell me that it is missing

Comment: Related (may or may not be a duplicate) - UTF-16 encoded source file: *[Running 'gcc' on C++ source file on Linux gives “cc1plus: out of memory allocating …” error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588296)*