# Running 'gcc' on C++ source file on Linux gives "cc1plus: out of memory allocating ..." error message

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I encountered a puzzling problem when compiling a C++ source file using 'gcc' on Ubuntu.  Having solved the problem I would like to publish it here to save others the headache of solving it.

For the sake of this report we have the simplest possible C++ "Hello, World" program, stored in main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the command:

```
gcc main.cpp
```

I get the error message:

```
cc1plus: out of memory allocating 1677721600 bytes after a total of 475136 bytes
```

I verified I was compiling for the correct bittage (i.e., 32-bit).  What was I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out I had saved the C++ source file as a UTF-16 Unicode-encoded file, complete with leading Unicode Byte Order Mark (BOM) bytes at the beginning of the file.  The file was saved as UTF-16 on a Windows system, committed to a version control system, then checked out to Linux.  gcc does support Unicode encoded as UTF-8, but not Unicode encoded as UTF-16.

The solution was to convert the source file back to a standard, non-Unicode encoding.

Comment: Huh.  You'd think you'd get something like a syntax error because of the characters that the compiler couldn't understand.

Comment: I would report this as a bug (assuming it still does this on a reasonably recent system). [I'd also investigate getting an editor, such as xemacs (or emacs if you prefer terminal mode) or eclipse onto your Ubuntu machine!]

Comment: @Michael Indeed, a proper syntax error would have saved me a good amount of time. Nothing matches the fun of thinking you've messed things up by mixing different bittages (e.g., 32- or 64-bit) but not finding any explanation.  Since I was building using CMake, there was another bogey man to worry about.

Comment: @Mats Reading the GCC 4.9. online docs (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/cpp/Character-sets.html#Character-sets), I see that GCC supports UTF-16 or UTF-32, depending on the size of wchar_t on your system.  My Ubuntu is 64-bit, where sizeof(wchar_t)=4.  Thus it probably would have accepted UTF-32.  Since my Windows has sizeof(wchar_t)=2, it saved the source file as UTF-16.  So I was trying to compile a UTF-16 encoded source file on a UTF-32 OS.  To keep my project cross-platform, it needs to be ANSI or UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Right, but it should probably fail with a more user friendly message than trying to allocate ginormous amount of memory! ;)

Comment: I accidentally did a `g++ file.cpp -o file.cpp` instead of `g++ file.cpp -o file` and received this warning every time I tried to compile thereafter. Same memory count as well. This was on Cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in compiling a `C++` program with a `MAKEFILE`.

I found an easy way to get rid of this problem and it is **delete the existing binary file from the previous compile**.

I could not identify the origin of the problem but That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler itself is a **32-bit** program, it might happen same compile error, especially on Windows for a cross-compiler.

For example, I encounter "cc1.**exe**"/"cc1plus.**exe**" failed to allocate very  big heap memory when compile a `.c`/`.cpp` file which defines a very big size global static array. My compiler is 32-bit windows program, part of the toolchain `gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-mingw-w64-i686-aarch64-none-linux-gnu.tar.xz`.

The corresponding Linux-64 host cross-compiler, within `gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64_be-none-linux-gnu.tar.xz`, is a 64bit program, and has no this error.

https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/gnu-a/9-2-2019-12