# cc1plus reports "out of memory"

Tags: c++, memory, compilation

So I'm attempting to compile a header file, a main file, and a function definition file together in Geany. I'm using the command

> user@cu-cs-vm:~/Dropbox$ g++ Assignment4.cpp CommunicationNetwork.cpp CommunicationNetwork.h -o Assignment4

But when it executes, I get the error message:
cc1plus: out of memory allocating 3355443200 bytes after a total of 548864 bytes.

Any idea of what could be happening?

Comment: Dang, your compiler is trying to use 3.3 gigs of memory!?

Comment: Maybe [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588296/running-gcc-on-c-source-file-on-linux-gives-cc1plus-out-of-memory-allocati)?

Comment: For one thing you should not be specifying .h files in your command line.