# How to diagnose g++ error "cc1plus.exe: out of memory allocating 838860800 bytes" in moderately sized project?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, g++

I'm attempting to port my [C++ library](https://github.com/mzabsky/geogen/) to g++ using rudimentary [makefile](https://github.com/mzabsky/geogen/blob/master/Makefile) (it compiles well in Visual Studio). The portion I'm trying to compile right now measures at about 45000 lines of code.

The library itself compiles OK, but when I attempt to include it into a console iterface application, the compiler crashes with following message and nothing else:

```
 cc1plus.exe: out of memory allocating 838860800 bytes
```

It happens when I include the main header of the project (which is machine generated and is not committed to the repo, see it [here on Gist](https://gist.github.com/mzabsky/d3028a576b6ee09c1d9f)).

I figured it is because the header is too large, but I noticed other projects have all-encompassing headers like this and don't suffer from these issues. I tried to strip down all non-essentials (to about 1/3rd, the rest was necessary for the application to compile) from the header and the problem persevered. I also noticed the number in the error message did not change at all, so I believe there is some singular issue causing the error, rather than it being caused by sheer volume of code.

There is very little template usage beyond usual STL and the code I'm compiling doesn't seem to be remarkable in any way.

I'm using g++ 4.8.1 under mingw32 on Windows 8.1 x64 with 16 GB of RAM. The code is being compiled with `-std=c++98`.

**How can I locate the code which is causing this issue?** g++ doesn't provide me with any diagnostic information to suggest the cause, even with the `-v` switch ([here is what it returns](https://gist.github.com/mzabsky/a8a9948f8c844bfdd1a6)).

Comment: are you using precompiled headers?

Comment: What happens if you remove `#pragma once`?

Comment: another post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588296/running-gcc-on-c-source-file-on-linux-gives-cc1plus-out-of-memory-allocati

Comment: @wallyk From the main header? Nothing, stays the same. I didn't try to remove it from the individual headers (that would probably break the compilation).

Comment: @MatějZábský:  It is in all the individual headers too?  I would remove them all and if it is desirable for that functionality to be anywhere, it should be in the build's command flags.

Comment: @MatějZábský:  How about running only the preprocessor to see if that is borking:  add `-E` to the command line.  If that is okay, then compile the `.i` output which *should* cause the original problem.

Comment: NB. Your code uses some c++11 features (non static default initialisers in class members (eg class C { bool arg = false; }; ), std::string arguments to std::ofstream). You’re also mixing / & \ in your includes all over the place.

Comment: However, your code with the include added from your gist compiles fine under Linux with the above errors fixed using g++-4.9.

Comment: @PhilArmstrong I'm aware of that. I don't think there is a way to enforce particular standard in VS, so I'm updating the code to comply with the standard now that I'm getting it to work with GCC.

Comment: Let's focus the ".exe" in the question. It's common that a cross-compiler is 32-bit program on Windows, and its counterpart is 64bit on Linux, and 32-bit program cannot allocate very big heap memory, which cause same test code encounter "cc1.exe/cc1plus.exe: heap allocation failed" on Windows, but Linux won't. For example,  `gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-mingw-w64-i686-aarch64-none-linux-gnu.tar.xz` and `gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64_be-none-linux-gnu.tar.xz` in https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/gnu-a/9-2-2019-12

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That happens when you try to compile a UTF-16 encoded file saved in Windows with gcc. Change encoding of your sources to UTF-8. See [related CPP documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html).

Comment: Thanks! The main header was indeed written in UTF16 by the script I use to generate it. Who would have thought incorrect encoding would cause GCC to allocate 800 MB of RAM.